# Google Like Pagination using Jquery

Tags: jquery, pagination

Here I have

```
<ul>
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li>
 <li>3</li>
 <li>4</li>
 <li>5</li>
 <li>6</li>
 <li>7</li>
 <li>8</li>
 <li>9</li>
 <li>10</li>
 <li>11</li>
 <li>12</li>
 <li>13</li>
 <li>14</li>
 <li>15</li>
 <li>16</li>
 <li>17</li>
 <li>18</li>
 <li>19</li>
 <li>20</li>
</ul>
```

initally Am showing only 10 li's, but when user comes to 10th page i need to hide visible 10 li's and show next 10 li's and should also work in vice versa using jquery ... Like pagination in google ..

I have tried with below code :

```
var currentIndex = $("div#pagination ul").children('li:visible').eq(-2).index(); 
var nextIndex = currentIndex + 10; 
$("div#pagination ul li:not(':first'):not(':last')").hide(); 
$('div#pagination ul li:lt(' + nextIndex + '):gt(' + currentIndex + ')').show();
```

first & last li is prev & next buttons, so i need show and hide between these buttons

Thanks ...

Solution : Not very effective but works ...

Solution :

```
var e = currentPage,r=lastPage;

if(e >= 10 && e<20)
{
    $("div#pagination ul li:not(':first'):not(':last')").hide();
    $("div#pagination ul li:lt(21):gt(9)").show();
}
else if(e >=20)
{
    $("div#pagination ul li:not(':first'):not(':last')").hide();
    $("div#pagination ul li:lt("+(r+1)+"):gt(19)").show();
}
else
{
    $("div#pagination ul li:not(':first'):not(':last')").hide();
    $("div#pagination ul li:lt(11):gt(0)").show();
}
```